# Hover on list item to get definition, place in different div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a couple questions.

This is an example of what i'm trying to make —

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGd5i.jpg

Theres a list of links in a scroll box. Beside that box theres another box that would hold a definition of the link.

My first question is, how would I grab the definition for each list item and place it in the other box?

My second question is, what would be the proper HTML tag/attribute to hold the definition of the list items in?

I'm not all that new to jQuery. just don't know about this.

Comment: have you looked at using ajax, jQuery hover even functions?

Comment: I'm gonna the fadein/fadeout with .hover() of course. But Ajax? The definitions will be really short. Wouldn't Ajax be to much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your second question, try `<dl><dt><dd>`. Where

```
<dl> = dictionary list
    <dt> = dictionary term </dt>
    <dd> = dictionary definition </dd>
</dl>
```

To use this with your project, you could hide the `<dd>` tag `display:none`.  When the `<dt>` is hovered, use Javascript to pull the sibling  element and place it's contents into that box on the right.

#### Edit

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('dt').hover(function(){
        var turnip = $(this).next('dd').html();
        $('#fullDefinitionBox').html(turnip);
    },function(){
        $('#fullDefinitionBox').html('&nbsp;');
    });
});
```

Comment: Use dl instead of ul? Or both?

Comment: Don't use both.  you could use `<ul>`, but it would be messier. `<dl>` is kind of like `<ul>`, except that it has 2 children element `dt and dd` instead of just one `li`.

Comment: Ok, what would be an example of the jquery to grab the content? I just need a short example

Comment: Hey it works but theres a duplicate of the definition that appears and stays

Comment: @Trippy We'd need to see more (the code, a fiddle, or the site) in order to help further.